How to make TypeScript see variable reassignments in lambdas?
I am running a lambda function predicate over a list of values to find the first value matching the predicate. However, in addition to finding the right value, I want to store the result of an internal calculation in the lambda function for later.
Simplified example:
let helper: number | undefined = undefined;
const array = [1, 2, 3];

const result = array.find((v) => {
  helper = v % 2;
  return helper === 0;
});

console.log({ helper, result });
if (helper !== undefined) {
  console.log(helper.toExponential());
}

Here, result should be the first value matching the predicate and helper should store the internal calculation, which I want to do something with later on. In order to consider the case where no value matches the predicate, I defined the type of helper to be number or undefined and check afterwards, if helper is a number before I do anything with it.
At runtime everything works as expected and the output is:
{ "helper": 0, "result": 2 }
"0e+0"

However, TypeScript complains:
Property 'toExponential' does not exist on type 'never'.

That is, TypeScript does not see the reassignment of helper within the lambda function. Because it does not see it, it deduces that the type of helper can be simplified to undefined.
How can I make TypeScript aware that I am reassigning a variable in a lambda function?
TypeScript Playground Link

Dont really see the point of the Helper. Why not check result variables? Find will already stop on first match

This is ms/TS#9998. Best approach is to assert helper as number | undefined instead of annotating it (to avoid assignment narrowing), as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find an existing question to link). If not, what am I missing?

@0stone0: In my real life example, helper will contain the result of an expensive computation. Of course I could re-run this computation after finding result, but that should be unnecessary.
Besides that, TypeScript should still be able to handle this case, no?

@jcalz: Yes, the linked issue seems to match! However, I do not understand your suggested solution of asserting instead of annotating. Could you write an answer for this? Does it work if TypeScript is set to strict?

You don't understand let helper = undefined as number | undefined; vs let helper: number | undefined = undefined;?  Or is it the terminology?  I've linked to an existing q/a above which explains everything. No, --strict doesn't help. ms/TS#9998 is the issue and nobody would want to use TS if you could ever make it "strict" this way, since that means almost every closure would reset narrowing.

Ah, this is what you meant! Ok, I don't really understand how TypeScript handles this differently because the inferred type of helper is still number | undefined, but I'm happy with that as a solution. Thank you!

The other answer talks about it; assignment narrowing causes helper to be narrowed to undefined when you annotate, and the narrowing never gets reset because of ms/TS#9998. The assertion blocks TS from being able to narrow, so there's nothing to reset. It's explained in the answer and the links within.
